# iOS: is it safe to use force unwrap on Locale.preferredlanguages.first?

Tags: ios, swift, localization

In my app I need the first `preferredLanguage` and I cannot use any fallback back mechanism so the things like `Locale.preferredLanguage.first ?? something else` will not do the trick for me. So, I'm thinking it is safe to assume that the app always has at least one preferredLanguage and just use the force unwrap. I mean the entire device cannot run without using some language therefore `preferredLanguage` array should always have at least one value! Are my reasonings correct ? I tried to Google this, but didn't find to much info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case it will always have a first value, and your code wouldn't crash if you would use a force unwrap. It is because you always have one development language at least.

But I think you should never rely on force unwrapped values. It is always better to use a guard-let or if-let to unwrap the value, and handle the error gracefully. For example you could show an alert with title: Internal error occured, and/or firing a Firebase or other type of log event.

```
guard let firstPreferredLanguage = Locale.preferredLanguages.first else {
    showAlert("Unexpected internal error occured.")
    logFatalErrorEvent("Locale.preferredLanguages was empty!")
    return
}
```